# how to get the content of java script object in another object?

Tags: javascript

how to get the content of java script object in another object ?
let say my variable are like follows :

```
var credentials ={
                 "name":userName,
                 "passwd":password
                 } 

var params={
       "Credentials":credentials
       }
```

am passing params as an parameter to same other function.In that function i have another object pkt ,as follows :

```
var pkt={
         "name":xxx,
         //XXXX
         }
```

what to code at XXXX so that my final pkt structure should be like:

```
pkt={
     "name":xxx,
     "Credentials": {
                   "name":userName,
                   "passwd":password
                    } 
    }
```

we may have multiple objects inside params,the requirement is that the key value pair should come accordingly.
the equivalent java code is as follows:

```
Iterator iterKeys = params.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterKeys.hasNext())
        {
            String key = (String)iterKeys.next();
            JSONValue value = params.get(key);
            pkt.put(key, value);
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects are just Hashmaps.

```
    var credentials = {
        "name": "userName",
            "passwd": "password"
    }

    var params = {
        "Credentials": credentials
    }
    var pkt = {
        "name": "xxx",
    }

    for (var property in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var value = property;
        pkt[property] = params[property];
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(pkt));
```

You can just assign as seen in [this fiddle]
(http://jsfiddle.net/TfWMy/)

Comment: This is setting the "params" property of the pkt object. What is required is setting the credentials property.

Comment: The requirement is to combine the objects, basically. Updated to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library function like [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
pkt = $.extend(pkt, params);
```

Otherwise you can loop through params and add each key/value pair to pkt:

```
for (var key in params){
    pkt[key] = params[key];
}
```

Use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid looping over ancestor members.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, though it would be helpful to actually show fully elaborated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use associative array structure.

i.e

```
var credentials = {
    "name": "userName",
        "passwd": "password"
}


var pkt = {
    "name": "xxx",
}

pkt["Credentials"] = credentials
```

Not particularly sure about this, but this should work as expected.

Comment: This hard codes the "Credentials" string, as opposed to using the object key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two quick functions that should do what you're looking for. The first adds the keys and values to a new object, the second function adds the keys and values to the first object.

```
var mergeObjectsToNew = function(o1, o2) {
    var r = {};

    for (var key in o1) {
        r[key] = o1[key];
    }

    for (var key in o2) {
        r[key] = o2[key];
    }

    return r;
}

var mergeObjects = function(o1, o2) {
    for (var key in o2) {
        o1[key] = o2[key];
    }

    return o1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to extend your object with another.

Please follow the code and I hope this is the thing you are require.

```
  var credentials ={
             "name":"",
             "passwd":""
   } 

  var params={
     "Credentials":credentials
   }

var pkt={
  name:"ABC"
};

function Extends(param1,param2){
  var object = $.extend({}, param1, param2);
  console.log(object);
}
Extends(params,pkt);
```

**Please find Fiddle Below**

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrUaj/)

Comment: This assumes the usage of jQuery!

Comment: Yes Neeraj this is using jQuery